# network programming basics, need help to understand addrinfo / sockaddr_in structs usage etc

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I started to learn C/C++ network programming but I am stuck at the beginning. I am kinda noob in programming but I understand basic stuff such as C libraries, pointers, structs,  etc. I cannot find well explained information about some details related to addrinfo / sockaddr_in structs. Amount of similar structs is annoying and online tutorials are messy. As additional information I can tell that I am programming on windows, using visual c++ 2010 express. I do not know if the information I already know is correct. I think it works that way:

1. sockaddr_in is no longer need to be created and filled manually anywhere because the function "getaddrinfo" does that for me, using the information I define manually inside addrinfo, so addrinfo is a thing to replace all sockaddr_in.
2. seems the HOSTENT struct is useless, as it is used in "gethostbyname" function and that became deprecated because of "getaddrinfo"

Now some questions:

How does introducing of "addrinfo" change usage of common functions - do any functions now take another arguments such as addrinfo instead of sockaddr_in as a part of them?

It seems that old-style programming without addrinfo is more beginner-friendly, I think I want to use sockaddr_in only for now as I only learn and want to make simple stuff, is that a good idea?

Please tell me if my understanding is correct and answer my questions if possible, comments or explanations are welcome.

**EDIT**
As I did not get direct answers explaining things I do not understand I did keep trying to figure out how it works and I probably understand these things a bit more.

The thing I want to know the most now is role of HOSTENT struct after "gethostbyname" got deprecated because "getaddrinfo" function made it useless. I want to know details because I want to know what I am doing in every part of the code.

Comment: If you're looking to learn in this level of detail, you may want [Stevens](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131411551/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0131411551&linkCode=as2&tag=kfsorg-20).

Comment: That is not big level of detail in my opinion, I think people who do C++ network programming know how usage of these structs work. I am also looking for confirmation that the information I gathered is correct. People who use getaddrinfo will know the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfortunately not going to answer your questions, however, I'd totally recommend to read the Beej's Guide, which is a great reference for getting started in a convivial way: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: I did already read that, Beej's guide is old (it encourages to use winsock.h what is ancient library now) and does not describe these structs well enough. I cannot find detailed information and it is hard to progress with such a mess with header usage changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Berkeley Socket API is 30 years old (born in 1983). So it's full of a lot of cruft. And the Windows Socket API is a multi-iterated "bsd-ish". Or, to put this another way, you're starting down something of a rabbit hole that you probably don't need to.

If you really want to understand the evolution of the API, you're actually going to have to turn to books - very likely Steven's "Unix Network Programming", and then read material on WinSock porting. But there's no one definitive source because Windows is not developed in transparency, and the last 10 years or so MS have been patchy at keeping their developers well informed (this is a case in point).

But if what you actually want to do is get into the practicalities of moving packets around the network, rather than the minutae of what the involved structures are, you might want to start by looking at a slightly higher level API such as "[libevent](http://libevent.org/)" (unfortunately, very C like) or "[ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)" or "AMQP" ([rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Apache qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/)).

Comment: I am not looking for evolution of API, but I have troubles to understand these basics as this is complex and hard to understand with changing stuff and new struct using outdated one as part of it, also source codes look not very logical (more like a mess than showing how it works) so I cannot answer by myself and I do not even know how to start coding to test this myself. Also i'd prefer to start from winsock than from alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

OK , I'm not sure what you are looking for in an answer. So I will attempt to take the general advise route. I completed a project last year and I went down the winsock route and while I'm sure there are any number of new ways I found I liked the winsock / sockaddr_in stuff ( altough I'm by no means a guru at any aspect of programming). I essentially started off with a simple server/ client pair that allowed two people to chat across an ad-hoc network. And I found the sockaddr_in structs intuitive enough to use. If you wanted to start off on a smaller scale you could have the server/client local on one machine by setting the client port as a loopback IP and have your client connect to this socket (either from within the same app via threads or have separate apps for your client and server). Just have your server listen for a connection and send a simple "Success" string or something. I got most of these ideas from a guy I found on youtube (Shocking I know !) Here's a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBAAbp6cNpg&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLq3NUY5CXcCq52VvqQ1fJ0XECaPfSqk5B) . Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: Thanks, you gave me good example for start with detailed description. And answer I am looking for are details about changes caused by really confusing struct "addrinfo" that replaced "sockaddr_in". Beej's guide is the only one mentioning what these structs have in common, and it is hard to find detailed information to understand the differences.

Comment: I only used the sockaddr_in so take this post with a pinch of salt !! At a glance it seems the addrinfo struct is composed of a few more data members than the sockaddr_in structure (including an instance of sockaddr itself..Also describes more about the socket it is associated with e.g TCP or UDP or RAW etc.).Perhaps if you were trawl through some MSDN documentation or a forum buried away somewhere you would strike gold and find someone giving a best used case analysis for these two. In my opinion I would start with the sockaddr_in approach and learn the basics. Hope this helps!